# Cannot find module "./src/home/home.jsx"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know there are about 1000 of these here on SO, but they all seem to reference problem with using the npm package manger and node_modules. My file structure (for the relevant files) is like this:

```
app
|
 main.js
|
 src
  |
   home
    |
     home.jsx
```

My main.js file is requiring the home.jsx file like this `import Home from './src/home/home.jsx';`

I have no idea as to why this would be a problem. I checked for extra spaces that I might have had on t he end of "home.jsx," but that wasn't it. This seems so simple, but I cannot for the life of me understand why this is happening.

If it matters at all, I am using webpack to bundle my files.

```
//webpack.config.js

var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './main.js',
  output: { path: __dirname, filename: 'bundle.js' },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
    resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  }
};
```

Comment: From the info you have given it should work. Have you configured webpack with jsx loaders?

Comment: Yeah, I am using babel, and have installed the babel-loaders and the babel-preset-react modules.

Comment: Is there something that I am possibly not doing in my webpack.config file?

Comment: Possibly, very hard to tell. As I said, from the information you have given everything seems correct. Make sure you have configured babel and webpack correctly. Possibly edit your post with your webpack and babel configurations if you would like people to be able to give you more detailed answers.

Comment: I just set up the exact same structure as what you have, and it worked perfectly. Make sure your home.jsx exports correctly, that you have babel-core, babel-loader as well as the presets you use installed.

Comment: Yeah, this was my problem, I didn't have export default before my component declaration.